# CSP blocking phpMyAdmin - any recommended Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: phpmyadmin, content-security-policy

I've added Content-Security-Policy header to my http.conf but now phpMyAdmin login page does not load properly

All I get is the phpMyAdmin logo and the text "Welcome to phpMyAdmin".

Upgraded to phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1 to no avail.

The CSP I'm using is:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self'"
```

Running macOS 10.14.x Mojave, Apache 2.4.39.

What is a CSP that is secure but also allows phpMyAdmin to run?

Thanks in advance,

James.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this to work.

In http.conf I put:

```
<Directory “/path/to/roundcube">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Then created /path/to/roundcube/.htaccess and it has:

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'"
```

Not sure if the first line with the ‘unset’ is needed.

After restarting Apache it works.